# How to Clean resources using teardown of junit class

Tags: junit4, powermock

I am using Junit4 in eclipse.

The tests are running successfully. but at sometimes, the eclipse got hangs and closes the workspace.

And I have to deploy my code into sonar jenkins. Iam unable to do a stable build with the Junit classes.
My Junit test case goes as follows.

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({UtilityFunctions.class,EmergencyDoDao.class,             
       EmergencyDoService.class,    
       EmergencyDoExport.class,EmergencyDoBusinessManager.class })
     public class EmergencyDoServiceTest {
/**
 * Run the EmergencyDoService() constructor test.
 *
 * @generatedBy CodePro at 9/19/13 12:00 PM
 */
@Test
public void testEmergencyDoService_1()
    throws Exception {
    EmergencyDoService result = new EmergencyDoService();
    assertNotNull(result);
    // add additional test code here
}

@Test
public void testGetEmergencyDoService_1()
    throws Exception {
    String dc = "5854";
    String beginDate = "1/1/2011 00:00 AM";
    String endDate = "9/18/2013 00:00 AM";
    String doStr = "*";
    String doStatus = "All";
    String shipment = "*";
    boolean isExport = false;
    String sortBy = "CreatedDate,OrderId";
    String fileType = "";
    BigDecimal scheduleId = null;
    BigDecimal jobId = null;
    EmergencyDoInputDTO inputDto = new EmergencyDoInputDTO();
    inputDto.setDc(dc);
    inputDto.setBeginDate(CommonUtil.convertToSqlTimeStamp(beginDate));
    inputDto.setEndDate(CommonUtil.convertToSqlTimeStamp(endDate));
    inputDto.setDoStr(doStr);
    inputDto.setDoStatus(doStatus);
    inputDto.setShipment(shipment);
    inputDto.setSortBy(sortBy);
    inputDto.setExport(isExport);
    inputDto.setFileType(fileType);
    EmergencyDoMockDAO.mockgetEmergencyDo(inputDto,scheduleId,jobId);
    Response result = EmergencyDoService.getEmergencyDoService(dc, beginDate, endDate, doStr, doStatus, shipment, isExport, sortBy, fileType, scheduleId, jobId);
    String output = result.getEntity().toString();
    Assert.assertEquals(true,output.contains("\"result\": \"Success\""));
}

@Before
public void setUp()
    throws Exception {
    // add additional set up code here
}

/**
 * Perform post-test clean-up.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 *         if the clean-up fails for some reason
 *
 * @generatedBy CodePro at 9/19/13 12:00 PM
 */
@After
public void tearDown()
    throws Exception {
    // Add additional tear down code here
}

/**
 * Launch the test.
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 *
 * @generatedBy CodePro at 9/19/13 12:00 PM
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new org.junit.runner.JUnitCore().run(EmergencyDoServiceTest.class);
}
```

After lot of struggling, I found that in the **teardown** of junit class, we can add code to clean the resources.

Can anybody suggest me how to clean the above resources in Junit, so that I can have a stable bulid in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any suspicious code that can possibly block and/or close Eclipse. IIRC setUp() and tearDown() was to init/clean up unit test resources in Junit3. In JUnit 4, it totally depends on @Before and @After annotations.

And can I ask what do you mean "Iam unable to do a stable build with the Junit classes"? If it's unstable build with JUnit classes, that's probably your unit test is broken. Either fixing broken unit test or just disable/delete them(if you don't think those unit tests are useful) would allow you to build stable build.